# css showing image when hover + animating the overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show the image when hover ... it has a liner gradient ..

I read that the gradient does not support animation yet .

Is there a hack to make it animate ? do I have to use `before` or `after` in some part?

This is what it looks like :

[Before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyyLP.png)

[After hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XFbF.png)

```css
.custom-box {
    padding : 50px;
    border : 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.custom-box:hover {
    background : linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7), rgba(0,0,0,.7)), url("https://images4.alphacoders.com/197/thumb-1920-197758.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover ;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-box">
  <h3 class="text-center display-3">TEST <i class="fas fa-plane"></i></h3>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transition directly on complex background property, but you can simulate by using other elements or pseudo-elements, and hiding/showing on hover with opacity property.

Example using pseudo-elements

```css
.custom-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border : 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}
.custom-box::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  transition-duration: 1s;
  background : linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7), rgba(0,0,0,.7)), url("https://images4.alphacoders.com/197/thumb-1920-197758.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover ;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom-box:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-box">
  <h3 class="text-center display-3">TEST <i class="fas fa-plane"></i></h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: that worked nicely .. but i would add `top:0` and `left:0` the image isnt placed correctly to the box

Comment: Seems to me that it is another question. In stackoverflow, we concentrate having single question at a time, for the answers to be reuse in the future. If you're still stuck with you new problem, let's ask a new question about it :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .custom-box {
        padding: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
      }

      .custom-box:hover {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
          ),
          url("https://images4.alphacoders.com/197/thumb-1920-197758.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="custom-box">
      <h3 class="text-center display-3">TEST <i class="fas fa-plane"></i></h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your solution